# Logging IN flex running flash player in normal mode (not in debug mode)

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to flex, so not sure if my requirement is a valid use case for flex 3.

I have a set of users who run my application in non debug mode. Off late they have been reporting lot of issues. But I am not able to debug as there is no log file.

Is it possuible in flex 3 to do logging in a file without running in debug version. I understand trace only works if we run application in debug version.

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Logging via flash trace statements to the console or via the FlashLog.txt (mm.cfg) require the debug flash player. There are alternative ways to output debug content that don't rely on this, though.

Here's a whole post I wrote on one method: http://labs.tomasino.org/2009/12/04/flash-as3-debug-logging/